# How to enable multi-selection in Primary SideBar of Visual Studio Code on my own extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for Visual Studio Code, and I create a new activityBar with some treeViews that display some data from a JSON file. I would like to have the possibility to multi-select some of the items displayed like we can multi-select files in the Explorer. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't multi-select with `Ctr//Shift click` in your tree?  Or do you want something else?

Comment: that's exactly what I want but I cannot do it by default, I have to enable it somehow

Comment: Do you want to select the files using your extension code?  And how are you going to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the multi-select feature you need to set the **canSelectMany** property to *true*.

```
const provider = new ModulesProvider(`${rootPath}`);

vscode.window.createTreeView('nodeDependencies', {
    treeDataProvider: provider,
    canSelectMany: true
  });
```

To specify additional parameters while creating the TreeView we need to use the *createTreeView* method instead of *registerTreeDataProvider*.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much.  And now how can I take all the selected items? I mean for example, I want by right clicking on the selected items to delete all of them, but still even if I select many, it just deletes the item clicked.

Comment: `vscode.commands.registerCommand('right-clicking.deleteSite', (item: Items) => {

  item.contextValue = "site";
  sitesProvider.delete(item.label);
  vscode.commands.executeCommand("workflow.refreshEntry");

 });`

Comment: that's the code I have at the extention.ts for the delete